# When will the instruction "filled-new-array" appear?

Tags: java, dalvik, dex, instructions

Now I want to see what dose this instruction's every argument actually mean, but no mater what way I used to write java code and, I had never seen filled-new-array in dex:

```
int[] iArr1 = new int[5];//just a new-array
int[] iArr2 = {3, 4, 5, 6};//a "new-array" and "fill-array-data"
```

I think iArr2 should generate a filled-new-array and the elements are
So, how to generate a filled-new-array instruction in dex file?

Every useful answer will be grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filled-new-array opcode is typically used when creating multi-dimensional arrays.

Either of the below should get you a filled-new-array instruction.

```
int[][] iiArr1 = new int[1][2];
int[][] iiArr2 = new int[][] { { 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9, 0} };
```

To find similar examples for other opcodes, I recommend looking at the tests for the dx tool, which have example java code to produce most opcodes. For example, [this test](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/dx/tests/070-dex-multianewarray/) has example java code that produces the filled-new-array opcode

Comment: Yes, the first line you give will get me filled-new-array.The second line just generates new-array and fill-array-data.When the array is 6 or more dimensions, it brings filled-new-array/range.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I could have sworn the second one produced a filled-new-array when I tried it, but I just tried it again and confirmed it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, new question please. :) Now I need the instructions:const-string/jumbo, not-int and not-long. But no matter how I written the java code, 'dx' tool of android generated 'xor' with -1, but not 'not-int' or 'not-long'. And there is just const-string without 'jumbo'. So could you tell me how should I do please, thanks a lot!

Comment: new question indeed :). It's better to create a new question, than to try to ask a new one in comments.